# Set Windows 8 to always prompt for username on boot

Tags: windows-8, boot, login

I have a Windows 8 Profession system with multiple users. When I boot the system, Windows always loads the profile of the last logged in user. How can I change this so that Windows will always prompt me to select the user?

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

**How to prevent Windows 8 from automatically logging in the last user**

http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-disable-automatic-logon-of-last-user-in-window-8/

Change the value`enabled` in the registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\UserSwitch` to 1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple method for you: Create a new user, log into that user, log out, and delete said user. Windows should prompt for a logon in the future.

If that doesn't work, perhaps your computer has been previously configured to to said profile. You can check this by opening a command prompt, and typing `control userpasswords2`. You should notice a checkbox that says "*Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer*". Make sure this **is** checked.

Comment: Windows does prompt for a login for accounts with passwords. Ideally, my goal is to always boot to the account selection screen instead of the login prompt for the previously logged in user.

Comment: @Wige - You just have to disable the default profile and following Nacho's instructions will do that..